# Should questions be asked again in another board if one does not answer?

Tags: support, moderation

I have asked a question about Mail-servers in ServerFault [How to correctly configure postfix and opendkim and let receiving server know all details mailed-by signed-by?](https://serverfault.com/questions/558629/how-to-correctly-configure-postfix-and-opendkim-and-let-receiving-server-know-al) and have also put a bounty on it.

I checked Stackoverflow and saw many questions related to Servers, including Postfix and OpenDKIM, they have received enough attention and maybe good answers too.

My question is, to get more attention.. Is it advisable to post the same question in multiple boards or request to move the question from one board to another to get more attention?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Crossposting is generally frowned upon. ServerFault, or any other site in the StackExchange network, really don't care about your deadlines. Adding a bounty is the best way to get more attention.

Comment: Alright, I guess I will have to re-ask the question in Stackoverflow then...

Comment: ?? @KarmicDice - did you not read? "Crossposting is generally frowned upon"

Comment: @Titanium .. Nope, Where is it written?

Answer (score 9):

If you feel that your question is on the wrong SE site, you can flag and request that a moderator move it to another SE site. This is preferable to cross posting.

Having said that it would appear that your question is on the correct site. Adding a bounty (as you have) will hopefully garner more interest.

As to your deadlines, they're not ours. We don't have an SLA with you or anyone. Questions get answered as and when someone decides to spend their time helping out.

If you have a deadline then you should consider spending some $(currency) on hiring someone to help you.

Comment: Your last 2 paragraphs were really not helpful. You haven't answered my question either. Just ranted about deadlines and that what I should've done and what is SLA and stuff..!

Comment: @KarmicDice: T.A.N.S.T.A.A.F.L.

Comment: Helpful, perhaps not; completely accurate, yes.

Comment: @MadHatter: I believe that my first two paragraphs fully answer the OPs question. Did you read the original revision of the OPs question where they whine on about having deadlines?

Comment: @Iain and MadHatter ... I am not sure if you read my question correctly. "My question is, to get more attention.. Is it advisable to post the same question in multiple boards or request to move the question from one board to another to get more attention?"

Comment: Sorry, Iain, it's KarmicDice's grumbles about the last two that prompted my comment above.  For the avoidance of doubt: your whole answer is as spot-on as ever!

Comment: KarmicDice: when asking existing communities of volunteers to help you for free, you may well find that sarcasm and whining (which you most certainly are doing) are not amongst the most effective tools for persuading others to assist you.  Your question has been answered above most ably by Dennis, and I notice that you have posted a comment that completely ignores his response as well.

Answer (score 5):

Cross posting is almost *always* a bad idea, and something that you'll find many don't react very positively to seeing. There are cases where you *can* do it, but:

- The question must be on-topic for *all* sites considered, ***according to the help center on each site***. Don't judge what is or is not on-topic by the presence of questions about it - they might be old, or just not noticed enough to close when they were asked.
- Tailor your question on each site to *best* fit that site's topic. If my question is about PHP and Wordpress, my Stack Overflow version of it is going to be more focused on the PHP aspects, and the Wordpress SE version of it would be more focused on the Wordpress specific aspects.

Essentially, if done right - you have not *cross posted*, but asked two similar but distinctly *different* questions on separate sites.

In your case, no - questions about how to configure a mail server are not on-topic for Stack Overflow. Some were asked and answered, but this was before we launched Server Fault.

If you don't get a good answer on a site devoted to the topic of the question, *revise* the question if possible (and/or) try another bounty - you can also increase your chances by sharing your question on Twitter, Facebook, etc.

Comment: Asked 11 hours ago : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643849/php-email-form-not-sending-mail-with-postfix-installed

Comment: +1 ed your answer because that is what happens when a Mod replies!

Comment: @KarmicDice Tim isn't a moderator, he's an [SE] employee. It'd be nice if they had different diamonds or something.